# radion button selection based on input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two radio buttons. Male and Female.
     I want to select any one of these radio button based on input given via $_POST from 
     another page. If the input is 'male' then respective radio button should be cheked.
     Any one pl help me to achieve this.

Comment: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way

```
$checked = $_POST['gender'];
<input type="radio" value="male" <?php if($checked=="male"){echo "checked"}; ?> > Male
<input type="radio" value="female" <?php if($checked=="female"){echo "checked"}; ?> > Female
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for this.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if(isste($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] == 'male') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }  ?> />  Male

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if(isste($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] == 'female') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }  ?> /> Female
```